# KVO: observing global NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I have static global NSNumber value and i need to observe it. If it was member of some object, i would have no problems whatsoever. But what do i do with global scope? I guess i could use

```
[globalVar addObserver:self forKeyPath:**integerValue** options:... ]
```

but that seems ugly because i might as well use "intValue" KeyPath and i need to observe NSNumber, not it's int part, even if it's the only part of it i''m using now.  Making this particular variable part of some class doesn't seem like a "right" think to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy answer: you can't. Observing is a software mechanism which fundamentally involves *method calls*, doing a store (i.e. a machine instruction) into a global variable provides no hook to hang the mechanism on.

The best option is to re-think your design. Think of storing the value in a singleton class and accessing/observing it there.

Hard answer: write your own *mutable* version of `NSNumber` (an instance of which is *immutable*) and have this class implement the key-value observing protocol (this class might just be a wrapper with an NSNumber instance variable). Now store and instance of this class in your global variable and add any observers you like to it.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this kind of thing is by making it a value reachable from some globally-available object, such as NSApp, or its delegate.

Answer (score 0):

CRD is right, "In KVO only the property is observed, not the value" Typically dictionaries or custom objects are KVO but not the leaves (values) themselves (numbers, strings). Facing a similar problem, I finally extended the NSNumber class making it [KVO compliant](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html).
Now if you are looking for different approaches to achieve notifications in your app, I would strongly suggest to read [this article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/five-approaches-to-listening-observing.html).